# Remove certain languages from Sublime Text 3

Tags: windows-7, sublime-text-3

This was easy in Sublime text 2, but how do I remove (or limit the number) of code syntax files accessible on the bottom right hand corner.

[image: Sublime languages]

For example put Pascal into a folder when it's backed up, but not used.